# How to determine character set, code page, or encoding in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, character-encoding

I have a list of files with names written in what seems to be a written in VISCII or some East Asian format (I know the language is Vietnamese). I want to use `iconv` to convert the filenames to UTF-8 but don't know what the current character set is. I've tried a few options and have gotten errors with `iconv`.

Here are some examples in the list of files:

`1 2 3 CHIA ðÈI LÈýI V-¦_(831641).mid
CON ð¦i¦NG CHUýNG TA ðI_(829013).mid
HAÌY SÈýNG CU¦NG TI¦NH Y-U_(830818)
M-Y TI¦NH Y-U_(830639).mid
NG¦i¦I CHI-ýN SIÌ -ýY_(830491).mid
SAO CH¦A TH-ýY HÈ¦I -M (A)_(829702).mid
TR-N MAÊNH ð-ýT TI¦NH NG¦i¦I_(829041).mid`

Conversion is supposed to turn out like this:

`1 2 3 chia ðÈI LÈýI V-¦.mid`

to

`1 2 3 chia đôi lối về.mid`

What is the best way to find the encoding? I've tried from `VISCII`, `cp936`, `cp1258` to `UTF-8` but nothing works.

FYI: I've installed the Vietnamese language pack and it seems to be working for some programs but for file explorer in Windows 10, it's not working. I'm thinking maybe change the default font to something that allows the character set, but I'd have to hack the registry in Windows 10.

Comment: you should upload one of the files.

Comment: @David Dai It's not the content of the files I'm converting, I just want to change the filenames (files are MIDI format).

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the Vietnamese language pack in Windows 10's Language and Region settings.

Threw me off because all the files were zipped up. I unzipped them before the language pack was installed, so all the filenames were converted from UTF-16 (or one of the East Asian encodings) to UTF-8 (which I don't think includes the Vietnamese character set) permanently.

I then installed the Vietnamese language pack, so when opening the files, the contents were read correctly with the proper character set, but the filenames remained the same.

All I had to do was delete the first unzip batch and unzip again and the proper character set was used.

Not entirely sure what happened behind the scenes, so can't offer a technical explanation but hopefully my high-level explanation helps someone in the future.